# In Python how do I sort a list of dictionaries by a certain value of the dictionary + alphabetically?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Ok, here's what I'm trying to do... I know that itemgetter() sort could to alphabetical sort easy, but if I have something like this:

> [{'Name':'TOTAL', 'Rank':100},
>   {'Name':'Woo Company', 'Rank':15},
>   {'Name':'ABC Company', 'Rank':20}]

And I want it sorted alphabetically (by Name) + include the condition that the one with Name:'TOTAL' should be listed last in the sequence, like this:

> [{'Name':'ABC Company', 'Rank':20},
>   {'Name':'Woo Company', 'Rank':15},
>   {'Name':'TOTAL', 'Rank':100}]

How would I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best approach here is to decorate the sort key... Python will sort a tuple by the tuple components in order, so build a tuple key with your sorting criteria:

```
sorted(list_of_dicts, key=lambda d: (d['Name'] == 'TOTAL', d['Name'].lower()))
```

This results in a sort key of:

- (True, 'total') for {'Name': 'TOTAL', 'Rank': 100}
- (False, 'woo company') for {'Name': 'Woo Company', 'Rank': 15}
- (False, 'abc company') for {'Name': 'ABC Company', 'Rank': 20}

Since False sorts earlier than True, the ones whose names aren't TOTAL will end up together, then be sorted alphabetically, and TOTAL will end up at the end.

Comment: wow, that was pretty slick... I like that, as it doesn't require creating a custom sorting algorithm either outside of that sorted() declaration.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lst = [{'Name':'TOTAL', 'Rank':100}, {'Name':'Woo Company', 'Rank':15}, {'Name':'ABC Company', 'Rank':20}]
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda d: (d['Name']=='TOTAL',d['Name'].lower()))
>>> print lst
[{'Name': 'ABC Company', 'Rank': 20}, {'Name': 'Woo Company', 'Rank': 15}, {'Name': 'TOTAL', 'Rank': 100}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [key](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sortingbykeys) parameter of sort or sorted.

For example:

```
dicts = [
     {'Name':'TOTAL', 'Rank':100}, 
     {'Name':'Woo Company', 'Rank':15},
     {'Name':'ABC Company', 'Rank':20}
]

def total_last(d):
    if d['Name'] == 'TOTAL':
        return '\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
    return d['Name'].lower()

import pprint
pprint.pprint(sorted(dicts, key = total_last))

>python sort_dict.py
[{'Name': 'ABC Company', 'Rank': 20},
 {'Name': 'Woo Company', 'Rank': 15},
 {'Name': 'TOTAL', 'Rank': 100}]
```

Comment: +1: Very clear with no lambda.  However, "sort_key" is an unwise choice of names.  `total_last` might be a more descriptive name for the key function.

Comment: Sorting by an arbitrary value that you expect to be last is not at all a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would sort it in multiple passes, using list's sort method.

```
list = [{'Name':'TOTAL', 'Rank':100}, {'Name':'Woo Company', 'Rank':15}, {'Name':'ABC Company', 'Rank':20}]

list.sort(key = lambda x: x['Name']) # Sorted by Name, alphabetically

list.sort(key = lambda x: 'b' if x['Name'] == 'TOTAL' else 'a')
```